# findAll returns empty set, logged raw query returns desired records

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm working with Sequelize and get this issue, findAll method return an empty array mean while the raw query which is generated work well. Here is my code:

```
import { format } from 'util';
    import sequelize from 'sequelize';
    import db from '../db';
    import { Assignment, AssignmentSchedules, GradingDailyTemplate, DailyTemplatePeriod } from './models';
    import { ASSIGNMENT_STATUS } from '../config/constant';

    async function changeAssignmentStatus() {
      const today = new Date();
      let month = today.getUTCMonth() + 1;
      month = month < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;
      let date = today.getUTCDate();
      date = date < 10 ? `0${date}` : date;
      const hour = today.getHours();
      const minute = today.getMinutes();
      const assignments = await Assignment.findAll({
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [
          {
            // get due date detail
            model: AssignmentSchedules,
            attributes: [],
            as: 'publishDate',
            required: true,
            include: [
              {
                model: GradingDailyTemplate,
                required: true,
                attributes: ['date'],
                where: sequelize.literal(`"date"::date = '${today.getUTCFullYear()}-${month}-${date}'`)
              },
              {
                model: DailyTemplatePeriod,
                required: true,
                attributes: ['timeFrom'],
                where: { timeFrom: `${hour}:${minute}:00` }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        where: { status: ASSIGNMENT_STATUS.READY_TO_ASSIGN }
      });
      console.log(assignments);
      if (assignments.length > 0) {
        const query = `UPDATE assignments SET status = ${
          ASSIGNMENT_STATUS.ASSIGNED
        } WHERE id IN (${assignments})`;
        db.query(query, { type: db.QueryTypes.UPDATE });
      }
    }
    export default changeAssignmentStatus;
```

generated raw query:

```
SELECT "assignments"."id", "publishDate->grading_daily_template"."id" AS "publishDate.grading_daily_template.id", "publishDate->grading_daily_template"."date" AS "publishDate.grading_daily_template.date", "publishDate->daily_template_period"."id" AS "publishDate.daily_template_period.id", "publishDate->daily_template_period"."timeFrom" AS "publishDate.daily_template_period.timeFrom" FROM "assignments" AS "assignments" INNER JOIN "assignment_schedules" AS "publishDate" ON "assignments"."publishDateId" = "publishDate"."id" INNER JOIN "grading_daily_templates" AS "publishDate->grading_daily_template" ON "publishDate"."gradingDailyTemplateId" = "publishDate->grading_daily_template"."id" AND "date"::date = '2019-09-23' INNER JOIN "daily_template_periods" AS "publishDate->daily_template_period" ON "publishDate"."dailyTemplatePeriodId" = "publishDate->daily_template_period"."id" AND "publishDate->daily_template_period"."timeFrom" = '12:20:00' WHERE "assignments"."status" = 1;
```

This is the first time I meet this problems, I also found a problem like this on Github of Sequelize but it was closed without any anwser. [findAll returns empty set, logged raw query returns desired records #7667](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7667)

Dialect:

> Postgres 10.10 Nodejs 12.10 Sequelize 5.8.6